# How to hide DIV's parent in JS with a specific content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide a DIV's parent when a certain DIV contains a specific text.

An example. This DIV I want to stay:

```
<div class="report-per-day">
<div class="report-day">26 May 2022</div>
<div class="status-report-rows">
<p class="report__headline">This is our report</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I want to hide this whole DIV, because there's a DIV .mt-2, which contains "No new incident."

```
<div class="report-per-day">
<div class="report-day">25 May 2022</div>
<div class="mt-2" style="display: none;">
<small class="text-muted">No new incident.</small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have this Java Script, but it only hides the .mt-2. I'd also like to hide its 2 parents, .report-per-day and .report-day

Do you guys happen to have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

```
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('mt-2');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    const div = divs[x];
    const content = div.textContent.trim();
  
    if (content == 'No incidents reported.') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the parent `div` you want to hide instead of `mt-2` and check the content of `mt-2` inside the loop. Try:

```
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('report-per-day'); // report-per-day instead of mt-2

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    const div = divs[x].querySelector('.mt-2'); // add a selector for .mt-2
    const content = div.textContent.trim();
  
    if (content == 'No incidents reported.') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use querySelectorAll().forEach, but I still like this answer more because it avoids the extra step of finding the parent element. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parentElement`

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('mt-2');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    const div = divs[x];
    const content = div.textContent.trim();
    if (content === 'No new incident.') {
        div.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="report-per-day">
<div class="report-day">26 May 2022</div>
<div class="status-report-rows">
<p class="report__headline">This is our report</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="report-per-day">
<div class="report-day">25 May 2022</div>
<div class="mt-2">
<small class="text-muted">No new incident.</small>
</div>
</div>
```